¿Como puedo cambiar de activity por boton usando un switch?
soy Nuevo programando, tengo este codigo el cual quisiera que cada boton al hacer click me mande a un activity diferente pero me marca este error "constant expression requiered". no se si este correcto usar un switch o un if else.


public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnInicio, btnBus, btnMod, btnMoneda, btnTer, btnSal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        btnInicio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIni);
        btnInicio.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnBus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
        btnBus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMod = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnModificar);
        btnMod.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnIni:
                startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, Inventario.class));
                break;
            case  R.id.btnBuscar:
                startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, BuscarPro.class));
                break;
            case R.id.btnModificar:
                startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, ModificarPro.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}




Primeramente revisa que dentro de tu layout activity_main2.xml se encuentren las vistas de los ids que tratas de referenciar:
 btnInicio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIni);
 btnBus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
 btnMod = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnModificar);

en este caso, asegura que existe en ese layout: btnIni, btnBuscar y btnModificar
